# Как сменить директорию сайта

Tags: .htaccess, apache

У меня в корневой папке хостинга есть два файла site1.php и site2.php также есть две папки с самими сайтами site1 и site2.

PHP файлы site1.php и site2.php выполняют include index файлов из папок site1 и site2.

Проблема в том что неправильно подгружаются стили, мне для правильной работы необходимо сменить в папках site1 и site2 ссылки на css, img, js. Но могу ли я при запросе к site1.php и site2.php изменить директории например в .htaccess или как либо еще? При этом не менять их в коде сайта site1/index.php

Получается в двух сайтах прописаны ссылки относительно корня, а мне необходимо к ним добавить названия папок site1 если запрос был к site1.php для корректной загрузки ресурсов.

Comment: для таких случаев делают виртуальные хосты и каждый сайт отвечает на своё доменное имя. Вам на хостинге нужно просто докупить ещё один сайт. Хотя я не вижу проблемы в папке site2 поменять все ссылки на site2 вместо site1. Современная IDE позволяет производить поиск и замену во всех файлах проекта

Comment: Это необходимо заказчику тут проблематика в том что он не сможет делать эти манипуляции. Нужно разместить два сайта на одном хостинге при этом запрос к ресурсам должен быть из одной директории и без редиректов.

Comment: Также в папках site1 и site2 могут быть разные сайты, он просто хочет загрузить в эти папки свои сайты и чтобы все работало относительно корня.

Comment: Если был запрос к site1.php сайт должен загрузиться из site1/index.php если к site2.php тогда из site2/index.php

Comment: Хорошо, допустим загрузка site1/index.php вместо site1.php решается прописыванием правил в .htaccess. Не понимаю в чём проблема для всех ресурсов site1 прописать все пути к site1/..., а для site2 - site2/... Например, у вас в site1/index.php будет `include "site1/config.php";`, а для site2/index.php - `include "site2/config.php";` ?

Comment: Я примерно так и сделал. У меня в /site1.php установлен include "site1/index.php" в site2 ровно тоже самое. Проблема только в том, что я получаю огромное кол-во 404 ошибок при запросе к site1.php и 2 т.к все ресурсы в папках site1 и site2 прописаны относительно корня / Мне просто необходимо сконфигурировать apache так чтобы при запросе site1.php и site2.php был маршрут к ресурсам например не assets/css/main.css а site1/assets/css/main.css тоже самое и для второго. Но я не занимался конфигурацией серверов, и не очень понимаю как это сделать.